# Passing username and password to sqlcmd,

Tags: passwords, sqlcmd

**Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'abc.pqr'..**

```
Begin
Declare @trcustomerid int = 16
Declare @cmd varchar(8000)

set @bcp = 'sqlcmd -S  servername,portname -U abc.pqr -P Password, -W -Q "set nocount on; SELECT * FROM [dbname].[schemaname].[tablename] WHERE id= '+ cast(@trcustomerid as nvarchar(10))+' "'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
END
```

---

OR  `set @bcp = 'sqlcmd -S  servername,portname -U abc.pqr -P Password, -W'`

is also giving **Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'abc.pqr'..**

basically, sqlcmd is not able to parse the passed password

How to resolve it?Please help

Comment: The above method works fine on windows authentication, but doesn't work on server authentication

Comment: I checked the logs too, it said "password did not match that for the login provided"..but the password is correct

Comment: sql server authentication with windows authentication is enabled